# Calculating quiz score for validation

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I'm not using the Quiz module; I am using Webform and Drupal 7.

I have created a quiz that, if passed, assigns the user a new role. Currently, I use validation rules to simply prevent wrong answers from validating; all questions must be answered correctly before the user can proceed.

I need to change this to allow users with a score of 80% or higher to proceed to the next quiz. I know that I can do that with the quiz module. However I also need to be able to show correct answers for missed questions only to users who scored between 80% and 100%. Those scoring below 80% may not see any answer key.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am solving this problem by disabling Quiz and using only Webform, and writing a custom module that does the following:

- use hook_form_alter to catch webform submissions
- compare them to fields in an answer key

  - answer keys are of content type 'answer key'
  - they have a node reference field that references a webform
- calculate percent that match
- display a message depending on score

  - if 80% < x < 100% display answers
  - if 80% < x return that the quiz was passed
  - if 80% > x tell them they failed and redirect them back to the quiz page to re-take the test.

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI I put together a webform quiz module that works with the formbuilder module. It allows you to put in a percentage that the user needs to pass to finish this quiz as well as putting a correct answer for each form component: http://drupal.org/sandbox/acouch/1817016